# Algorithm - Weighted interval scheduling problem variant

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, pseudocode

So I have a problem that goes as follows:

> Xzqthpl is an alien living on the inconspicuous Kepler-1229b planet, a
>   mere 870 or so light years away from Earth. Whether to see C-beams
>   outside Tannhäuser Gate or just visiting Sirius for a good suntan,
>   Xzqthpl enjoys going on weekend trips to different faraway stars and
>   galaxies. However, because the universe is expanding, some of those
>   faraway places are going to move further and further away from
>   Kepler-1129b as time progresses. As a result, at some point in the
>   distant future even relatively nearby galaxies like Andromeda will be
>   too far away from Kepler-1229b for Xzqthpl to be able to do a weekend
>   trip there because the journey back and forth would take too much
>   time. There is a list of "n" places of interest to potentially visit.
>   For each place, Xzqthpl has assigned a value "v_i" measuring how
>   interested Xzqthpl is in the place, and a value "t_i" indicating the
>   number of weeks from now after which the place will be too far away to
>   visit.
>
> Now Xzqthpl would like to plan its weekend trips in the following way:
>
> 1. No place is visited more than once.
> 2. At most one place is visited each week.
> 3. Place "i" is not visited after week "t_i"
> 4. The sum of values "v_i" for the visited places is maximized
>
> Design an efficient (polynomial in "n" and independent of the v_i’s
>   and t_i’s assuming the unit cost model) algorithm to solve Xzqthpl’s
>   travel planning problem.

Currently I don't really know where to start. This feels like a weird variant of the "Weighted Interval Scheduling" algorithm (though I am not sure). Could someone give me some hints on where to start?

My inital thought is to sort the list by "t_i" in ascending order... but I am not really sure of what to do past that point (and my idea might even be wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify this phrase: *"independent of the v_i’s and t_i’s assuming the unit cost model"*?

Comment: @trincot It's basically saying that the time complexity should be polynomial in "n" and use the unit cost model (https://yourbasic.org/algorithms/unit-cost-vs-bit-cost/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a min-heap for this:

### Algorithm

1. Sort the input by *t<sub>i</sub>*
2. Create an empty min-heap, which will contain the *v<sub>i</sub>* that are retained
3. Iterate the sorted input. For each *i*:

   - If *t<sub>i</sub>* < size of heap, then this means this element cannot be retained, unless another, previously selected element is kicked out. Check if the minimum value in the heap is less that *v<sub>i</sub>*. If so, then it is beneficial to take that minimum value out of the heap, and put this *v<sub>i</sub>* instead.
   - Otherwise, just add *v<sub>i</sub>* to the heap.
   - In either case, keep the total value of the heap updated
4. Return the total value of the heap

### Why this works

This works, because at each iteration we have this **invariant**:

The size of the heap represents *two* things at the same time. It is both:

- The number of items we still consider as possible candidates for the final solution, and
- The number of weeks that have passed.

The idea is that every item in the heap is assigned to one week, and so we need just as many weeks as there are items in the heap.

So, in every iteration we try to progress with 1 week. However, if the next visited item could only be allowed in the period that has already passed (i.e. its last possible week is a week that is already *passed*), then we can't just add it like that to the heap, as there is no available week for it. Instead we check whether the considered item would be better exchanged with an item that we already selected (and is in the heap). If we exchange it, the one that loses out, cannot stay in the heap, because now we don't have an available week for *that* one (remember its time limit is even more strict -- we visit them in order of time limit). So whether we exchange or not, the heap size remains the same.

Secondly, the heap has to be a heap, because we want an efficient way to *always* know which is the element with the *least* value. Otherwise, if it were a simple list, we would have to scan that list in each iteration, in order to compare its value with the one we are currently dealing with (and want to potentially exchange). Obviously, an exchange is only profitable, if the total value of the heap increases. So we need an efficient way to find a *bad* value fast. A min-heap provides this.

### An Implementation

Here is an implementation in Python:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from heapq import heappush, heapreplace

Node = namedtuple("Node", "time,value")

def kepler(times, values):
    n = len(values)
    # Combine corresponding times and values
    nodes = [Node(times[i], values[i]) for i in range(n)];
    nodes.sort() # by time

    totalValue = 0
    minheap = []
    for node in nodes:
        if node.time < len(minheap): # Cannot be visited in time
            leastValue = minheap[0] # See if we should replace
            if leastValue < node.value:
                heapreplace(minheap, node.value) # pop and insert
                totalValue += node.value - leastValue
        else:
            totalValue += node.value
            heappush(minheap, node.value)
    return totalValue
```

And here is some sample input for it:

```py
times = [3,3,0,2,6,2,2]
values =[7,6,3,2,1,4,5]

value = kepler(times, values)
print(value) # 23
```

### Time Complexity

Sorting would represent *O(nlogn)* time complexity. Even though one could consider some radix sort to get that down to *O(n)*, the use of the heap also represents a worst case of *O(nlogn)*. So the algorithm has a time complexity of *O(nlogn)*.